# AngularJs Adding methods to controller from a component

Tags: angularjs, controller, components

I want two different components that share the same controller.
But I want to add an extra method for each component and only have that method available when that component is being used.

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
app.component('myComponent',{
  templateUrl: 'mytemplate.html',
  controller: 'myController', ['myService', function(myService){
    //extra things here  
  }]
});
```

Then my second component would be similar, but would do something else inside the controller method.

I know this doesn't work, but is there a way to make this work? or a better way to make this work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to use $broadcast subscription 
take a look here
https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/